# Keep login and password for proxy while clearing all passwords

Tags: firefox

I'm using Firefox 29.0.
Is there a way to keep login and password for proxy while clearing all passwords in cache?
Maybe there is something like local-machine proxy that keeps logins and passwords for LAN-proxy?

Answer (score 0):

If it's an HTTP proxy using HTTP basic or digest authentication, you can provide the proxy URI in the format `http://user:password@hostname`. Of course, this does expose your credentials to anyone who can see your proxy settings, which is marginally less secure than "saving" your password. (Saving your password is far more secure if you have a master password set.)

Comment: Thank you, @Bob. But where can I write this? In address I wrote IP, not   http://user:password@hostname

Comment: @oventarb The IP would be the hostname. So `http://user:password@ip` should work.